# How use LaTeX counters to label knitr code chunks?

Tags: cross-referencing, r, knitr

Imagine one has the LaTeX environments Example and Solution defined from the theorem environment.  I have several Examples in numerous child documents which make up a book.  LaTeX will automagically track the chapter and Example, Solution, Figure, etc number for  a labeled Example, Solution, Figure, etc., respectively.  Suppose the first code chunk below corresponds to the 6th Example in Chapter 4 of a book.  Then \ref{SetSeed} will return the number 4.6 when using \documentclass{book}.  I would like to be able to provide names to my code chunks that will stay in synchronization with the labels of my different LaTeX environments (Example, Solution, Figure, etc.).  What I do not want to do is hard code my code chunks with 'Example 4.6', etc.  Any suggestions would be most welcome.  I am aware of the code chunk options Yihui has for figure captions and labels but would be willing to do an "old style" code chunk surrounded with a \begin{figure}, \end{figure} environment if the code chunks can be named appropriately.  The thought is that the named code chunk might be generated with something like

```
<<paste(Solution,'\ref{SetSeed}', sep=" "), echo = TRUE>>=    ...(which does not work)
```

to generate the named chunk 'Solution 4.6'.  The rationale is to be able to later purl() the master document to produce labeled code chunks from the individual chapters that correspond to the environments (Figure, Example, Solution, etc.) displayed in the book.  Thanks in advance, Alan.

```
\begin{Example} \label{SetSeed}
Use the function \texttt{set.seed()} with a value of 13 and generate 
20 values from a normal distribution with a mean of 100 and a standard 
deviation of 15.  Find the mean of the randomly generated values.
\end{Example}

\begin{Solution}  
<<paste(Solution,'\ref{SetSeed}', sep=" "), echo = TRUE>>=
# some R code
set.seed(13)
xs <- rnorm(20, 100, 15)
@
The mean of the values generated in Example \ref{SetSeed} have a 
mean of \Sexpr{mean(xs)}.
\end{Solution}
```

Comment: Can you lay your question out better? That's a lot of text in one chunk!

Comment: Yes.  I did not format the initial question to display properly.  Sorry.

Comment: This might be hard, since the flow of information is one-way from R to LaTeX.  That is, knitr gets run *before* LaTeX, and completely in ignorance of any LaTeX machinery ... you might be able to produce a chunk named something like "Solution\ref{setSeed}", but getting one named "Solution4.6" would be hard ... ?  Apparently `brew` is more flexible, although I haven't used it

Comment: Why do you want the chunks to have the same name as the environment (and number) they fall within, I don't understand why this would be of interest or necessary...

Comment: Some people ask also for automatic labelling in LaTeX, and the problem is essentially the same:  Beside the technical difficulty to obtain that, the important issue is the utility of that, The name `xxxx` of the chunk is used to warning you about where is some error i s in `xxxx`  ... now what?. The `xxxx` name is also used to label the R figures as `fig:xxxx`.  Now you want include  a reference  to that figure, but now you can not be sure that label will be `xxxx`or something ... what a mess!

Answer (score 1):

That is a challenging problem. As Ben Bolker pointed out, it is a one-way flow: when R is done, nothing will come back from LaTeX to R again, so R will not be able to know the value of `\ref{SetSeed}` in LaTeX.

However, I do not think it is completely impossible, because you actually have the `*.aux` file generated from LaTeX, which you can parse with R for the solution numbers, and update the raw R script from `purl()` with this information. One approach is that you use the same label for the R chunk as you used for the `Example` environment, and you will get a code chunk in the output like:

```
## @knitr SetSeed
# R code
```

Hopefully you will also see this in the `*.aux` file after you have run LaTeX on the `*.tex` file:

```
\newlabel{SetSeed}{{1}{1}}
```

Then you replace `SetSeed` in the R code with `Solution 1.1`. In all, you need some post-processing of the R script.

Comment: Thanks.  I will have to think about that approach deeper over the break.